# How to sort in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting

I would like to get the cars ordered by descending order by their km variable and limited to a fixed number entered by the user. Sort is not working fine.

```
router.get('/cars/:limit', (req, res) => {
    const limit = req.params.limit;
    const query = Car.find().sort({ 'km': -1 }).limit(_.toNumber(limit));
    query.exec(function (err, cars) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        } else {
            res.json(cars);
        }
    });
});
```

Could you please help me to sort it?

Thanks!

Comment: So, what's wrong for you?

Comment: console.log(limit). it maybe resulting in 0 after _.toNumber()

Comment: Wha'ts wrong is that sorting is not working fine.